# C++11 Lambda woes

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Any ideas why the following code segfaults?

`class foo` represents any class. This seams like a good idea for providing an evented interface.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class foo
{
public:
  foo()
  {
    val = 42;  
  };

  void bar(std::function<int(foo*)> f)
  {
    this->_bar = std::bind(f, this);
  }
  std::function<int()> _bar;
  int val;
};

int main(void)
{
  foo *foobar;
  foobar->bar([](foo *self)->int{return self->val;});

  std::cout << foobar->_bar();
}
```

Comment: Before using lambdas you should start to read a proper book, see the list of good books. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Why do you cal it "evented"? And what is a "good idea" that you want to provide?

Comment: SO didn't let me post the code w/o 2 lines of desc.
I found the bug as soon as I posted, but I couldn't delete the post.
The good idea is using std::bind to give access to the current object. ie: pass the lamda that takes args self and then then some other thing, and binding the self argument to the this pointer.    

[entity.h](https://github.com/Tvorba/Tvorba-gfx/blob/master/entity.h)
[entity.cpp](https://github.com/Tvorba/Tvorba-gfx/blob/master/entity.cpp)

my main problem is coding when I am very sleep deprived.

Answer (score 6):

It segfauls because `foobar` is not pointing to anything, you should use `foo foobar;`.

EDIT:

A short review.

```
class foo
{
public:
  foo()
  {
    val = 42;  // Use initialization list.
  };

  void bar(std::function<int(foo*)> f) // Use reference (foo&) instead of pointer (foo*).
  {
    this->_bar = std::bind(f, this); // Move "f" into bind and use "std::ref()" so you can pass "*this" by reference without copying.
  }

  // Hide local member variables

  std::function<int()> _bar; // Never use _ as a prefix, only the compiler is allowed to use _ prefix.
  int val;
};

int main(void)
{
  foo *foobar; // Use value semantics, i.e. "foo foobar".

  foobar->bar([](foo *self)->int{return self->val;});

  std::cout << foobar->_bar();
}
```

e.g.

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo()
        : val_(42)
    {
    };

    void set_bar(std::function<int(foo&)> f)
    {
        bar_ = std::bind(std::move(f), std::ref(*this));
    }

    int invoke_bar() const
    {   
        return bar_;
    }

    int get_val() const
    {
        return val_;
    }

private:

    std::function<int()> bar_;
    int val_;
};

int main(void)
{
  foo foobar;
  foobar.set_bar([](foo& self) -> int
  {
     return self.get_val();
  });

  std::cout << foobar.invoke_bar();
}
```

Comment: No, he shouldn't. You just told someone to use `new` who obviously doesn't know any deeper concepts of dynamic memory, RAII etc. He is now probably going to leak and keep on using this pointer madness.

Comment: Names that begin with `_` are reserved only when underscore is followed by uppercase letter or for names in the global namespace. There is nothing wrong with using names starting with `_` followed by lowercase letter for class members.

Comment: "Underscores (`_') are often used in names of library functions (such as "_main" and "_exit"). In order to avoid collisions, do not begin an identifier with an underscore." From "Programming in C++, Rules and Recommendations"(http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/c++.rules/chap5.html).

Comment: i found the issue... but never clicked the submit button beofre a crash.

Answer (score 3):

You never create a foo, you just declare a pointer to it. Change `foo* foobar` to `foo foobar` and then get the address to it with `&`. (Not that you need it in this example).

This should work I guess.

```
foo foobar;
foobar.bar([](foo* self){return self->val;});
std::cout << foobar._bar() << std::endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: He could also use a reference for the lambda argument, instead of a pointer.

Comment: @ronag The way he uses it would then require him to dereference `this` in the call though. I thought this looked a bit nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you declared a foobar pointer but didn't use `new` to allocate memory for it. `foo *foobar = new foo();` should make your code work. But you also use automatic storage duration and pass parameter to lambada by reference:

```
int main(void)
{
  foo foobar;
  foobar.bar([](foo *self)->int{return self->val;});

  std::cout << foobar._bar();
}
```

Comment: No, he shouldn't. You just told someone to use `new` who obviously doesn't know any deeper concepts of dynamic memory, RAII etc. He is now probably going to leak and keep on using this pointer madness.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one seems to have said it explicitly: your problem has nothing to do with lambda; you would have exactly the same problem with a normal functional object, or with an immediate function call.  Before worrying about lambda and other "advanced" features, you must learn the basics of the language.  In this case:

1. You can never use an uninitialized variable, ever.  The results of doing so with a pointer are generally more spectacular than when you use an uninitialized `int`, but it is undefined behavior in all cases.  If a variable has class type, define constructors for it, which initialize all members (and base classes).  If a variable doesn't have class type (and a pointer does *not* have class type), never define it without an initialization clause.
2. C++ uses value semantics by default.  Unless there is a good reason, you should *not* use pointers.  Use a value.

Until you can write code which respects these principles without using `bind` and `lambda`, you shouldn't be looking at `bind` and `lambda`.  You can't run until you know how to walk.